# Windows service user account can't access the certificate store

Tags: windows, certificate, private-key, condor

## Background

I have a Windows 7 VM with two user accounts (condor_usr1 and condor_usr2) that is used for source code compiling.  The condor_usr[1|2] accounts are members of the administrators group.  I have an HTCondor master VM that periodically receives jobs and assigns each job to run on one of the condor_usr[1|2] accounts.  The condor service on the Win7 VM runs as the local system account, but jobs being executed actually run as the condor_usr[1|2] account.

I have a new requirement to sign the compiled executable.  I've imported the certificate with private key into the Current User\Personal key store in the Windows Certificate store.

## Problem

If I'm logged into the Win7 VM (e.g. via remote desktop) as one of the condor_usr accounts, then compiles running as that account will successfully sign the executable, but compiles running as the other account will fail to sign the executable.  For example, if I'm logged in as condor_usr2, then compiles running under condor_usr2 will sign successfully and compiles running under condor_usr1 will fail to sign.  If I log out, both accounts fail to sign.

The specific error I receive is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9): error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Turned on some audit logging and found the following log that occurred at the same time as a signing failure.

[image: signing failure]

## Goal

Sign the compiled executable successfully regardless of which account the compile is running as and without requiring a user to be logged in.

## What I've Figured Out So Far

- The code/project being compiled is a Visual Studio 2017 solution.
- The signing method is ClickOnce manifest signing (an option in the VS2017 project).
- When a compile job is started, the job logs in as condor_usr[1|2] using logon type 2 (interactive logon).
  https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-logon-types.html

[image: logon type]

## Things I've Tried

Unless otherwise noted, these actions had no effect and were reverted.

- Adding the condor_usr accounts to the Cryptographic Operators group.
- Importing the certificate w/ private key to the Local Computer\Personal key store.

  - Granting the Network Service account full control to the certificate/private key.
    https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/technicaltipsandtricksfordynamicsnav/posts/how-to-grant-access-to-the-certificate-s-private-key-to-the-service-account-for-microsoft-dynamics-nav-server
- Using `PsExec -h make.bat` to obtain the account's elevated token.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec
- I considered that User Account Control (UAC) may be preventing the system account and/or condor_usr account from accessing the certificate store (or private keys in the cert store), but UAC is already disabled on the Win7 VM.
- I placed the original .pfx certificate file in the VS2017 solution and targeted it instead of the certificate in the key store.  This had no effect, which leads me to believe that the issue is some sort of signing permission rather than (or perhaps in addition to) purely permissions around the actual certificate store.
- I tried starting a job while logged in via remote desktop, and then logging out of the remote desktop session (actual logout, not disconnect) before the job got to the signing portion.  Signing failed.

Comment: I'd also add this to my checklist: - I have the following folders created: `%windir%\system32\config\systemprofile\desktop` and `%windir%\syswow64\config\systemprofile\desktop` (64-bit OS only)

Comment: I don't understand how those paths relate to the problem...

Comment: Microsoft Office (saw some Office namespace in the error mesage) applications and its COM Interop sometimes require a desktop folder. Under a non-interactive session this `desktop` folder will be the used one. It's worth to try. If you search those paths on the internet, you'll see many posts saying `how those paths relate to the problem, but it worked`.

Comment: Your comment still isn't clear.  I tried googling and searching SO for that path, but I didn't find anything even remotely related.  What am I supposed to do with that path?  Perhaps you'd like to post a full answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure all the accounts involved in the process has the "Logon as service" rights by ensuring they are present in the local policy "Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Log on as a service". Note that this change becomes effective the next time the owner of the account(s) logs on.

Try running the HTCondor service directly as "condor_usr1" instead of the "Local System" account.

Comment: I was quite hopeful that this would work, but the compile still fails with the same error message.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: The HTCondor service may be impersonating the users in a way that could cause issues accessing the certificate store. Have you tried running the service directly as "condor_usr1" instead of the "Local System" account, and start a job targetting "condor_usr1"? Does it works without being logged in as "condor_usr1"? Also, the part where you tried targeting the PFX file directly but it didn't work, what was the exact error or trail? The error says "file not found", perhaps the signing tool or the compiled outputs are missing or at the wrong place (ie PATH issue)?

Comment: When directly targeting the PFX file, the error/failure was identical to the original error.  The compiled outputs are always in the same location, and I'd be surprised if the signing tool moved.  I'll try running the HTCondor service as condor_usr1.

Comment: Running the HTCondor service as condor_usr1 results in a successful compile for jobs running under condor_usr1, but this prevents condor_usr2 from processing any jobs.

Comment: Interesting, a workaround could have been to run two separate services (one for each user) but unfortunately HTCondor doesn't seem to support that. I highly suspect that a required piece (or a reference) is missing after the service impersonate the user. At this point, I would bypass the built-in signing feature and do it manually [like this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1225324/How-to-Sign-ClickOnce-Deployment-if-ClickOnce-Code).

Comment: I really think the issue is related to the user (Local System account vs condor_usr) and some permission (e.g. accessing the certificate store, etc) rather than the actual signing event, so I'm doubtful that changing the way the app is signed will make a difference.  There is a way to configure HTCondor with two job slots, where both slots use the same user (e.g. condor_usr1).  I'm going to try that with running the service as the condor_usr1 account.

Comment: Success!!  @Megabit, can you edit your answer and add `Try running the HTCondor service directly as "condor_usr1" instead of the "Local System" account`.  Once that is done I'll accept your answer (but we need to be quick since the bounty runs out in a few hours).

Comment: Done! Glad you finally fixed this issue since I think you had it for a while !

Comment: Yes, this has been an issue for a very long time.  Thank you @Megabit very much for your help, I couldn't have done it without you.